# Cursor in Select Clause of an sql Statement in JDBC

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, cursor

I have a query in which I am using Cursors in Select clause along with some other columns Values.I wanted to iterate through  its result via ResultSet in Java.But couldn't find a way to get the Cusror from the result set.Is it possible to do so?Can anyone help me?

For eg

```
select name, roll_no,
    cursor (select subj1 
        from Subject
        where id = 'abc' 
        ) as cusr1
from student
```

Comment: An example would likely be very helpful.  I'm not sure what you mean by "using cursors in [a] select clause".  Maybe you really mean that you're using the `cursor` function.  But that sort of guessing rarely works out well.

Comment: sorry, have added the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here would be a generic way to read columns from a ResultSet.

```
    while (resultSet.next()) { //Read every row
        int columnCount = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) { //Read every column
            String columnName = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(column);
            Object value = resultSet.getObject(columnName);
            if (value != null) {
                doSomething(columnName, value);
            }

        }         
    }
```

Comment: I am unsure how this answers this specific question; it just shows a generic way of processing a `ResultSet`.

Comment: Hey Mark you are right. By the time I answered this question there was no select example. For sure he can also get the value of the curser with resultSet.getObject(3)) I posted this exampled because I used it lately and thought it might help.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using an Oracle DB.
I also assume Java 7 or higher (try with resources).

You are using a Cursor Expression in your SQL.

The Oracle JDBC Driver returns a `java.sql.Resultset` object when you call `Resultset.getObject(column number|column label)` for a Cursor Expression column.

So it is safe to cast:

```
try (Resultset innerResultset =  (Resultset) outerResultset.getObject(column number/label)) {
    while(innerResultset.next()) {
    ...
}
```

One comment: In many cases, for example when creating "master-detail" queries, you use a correlated Cursor Expression, meaning there is a join on a table that appears in the outer query.